# Angular + Electron ipcRenderer event state problems

Tags: angular, event-handling, electron

**Solution at the end**

I am building a Angular + Electron application where I want to be able to drop image resources straight into the desktop window, this will trigger a create flow where I save the image onto the local filesystem.

The basics is up and running, but I've walked into a tricky situation where it seems like the angular application loses it's sense of state completely. When getting a message from the electron main process, using ipcRenderer for listening on the message "url-activated" the code execution seems to get out of phase with the angular execution cycle.

In the callback from ipcRenderer I execute a route navigation. This is where things turn weird. The route navigation seems to get stuck somewhere in the middle, sometimes I get stuck between the current route and the next, this gets solved by interacting with the application (seems like when the angular app executes it's change detection it handles some of the previously executed actions, like switching properly to the next route).

The application at this point is pretty wonky, I need to do additional actions to make the app behave and execute previous interactions (an example is that when I try to open a select box to see the options, this does nothing, but when I open the sidenav the select box options appear). It feels like the application run-time process has gotten severely out of sync in other words.

It feels like it all roots back to the ipcRenderer event, I might not handle it correctly, but I'm at loss to find a good way to go about it. Here's a code snippet of the current solution:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.electronService.isElectronApp) {
    this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on('url-activated', (event, data) => {
      let json = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log('We\'ve gotten an url from the main process', json.url);

      this.assetService.setBase64(json.imgStr);
      this.assetService.setImagePath(json.url);

      this.navigateTo('/image/create');
    });
  }
}
```

On the main process in the electron app we have this:

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', (event, url) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Wants to navigate to ' + url);

  if (url.match('file:///')) {
    var path = url.substr(8, url.length);
    base64Img.base64(path, (err, data) => {
      mainWindow.webContents.send('url-activated', JSON.stringify({ url: url, imgStr: data }));
    });
  } else {
    base64Img.requestBase64(url, (err, res, body) => {
      mainWindow.webContents.send('url-activated', JSON.stringify({ url: url, imgStr: body }));
    });
  }
}
```

With some tweaking using timeouts and manual change detection I get it in half working condition, but still get a lot of bugs when it comes to basic interaction with the DOM, so it feels like my communication with the electron main process is the culprit in all this.

I'm using the [ngx-electron](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron) plugin for the angular part of the communication,

and you can find the complete project on my github [art-companion](https://github.com/Fagertveit/art-companion)

Getting to the bottom of this problem will probably be of great learning for me and others that might stumble across the same problems.

**Solution**

I did some more testing with Zone after getting the comment from @estus and seems to have stumbled upon a solution, here's how it looks in code:

```
this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on('url-activated', (event, data) => {
  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    let json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('We\'ve gotten an url from the main process', json.url);

    this.assetService.setBase64(json.imgStr);
    this.assetService.setImagePath(json.url);
  });

  this.ngZone.runTask(() => {
    this.navigateTo('/image/create');
  });
});
```

Comment: This may be Zone.js issue. Try to wrap the code in `ipcRenderer.on` callback with `setTimeout` to check if it's the problem.

Comment: @estus Zone seems to have been the issue, I actually managed to solve the problem by running the code using zone.runOutsideAngular() and then executing the navigation function with zone.runTask() inside that scope! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Yes, that's how it's usually done. setTimeout is a quick way to test for it. You're welcome.